# Augmenting the prototype of DOM element nodes?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

I know how to add new methods to every object - by augmenting the Object's prototype:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function() {  };
```

But, is it possible to define new methods for DOM element nodes only? Do DOM element node objects have a prototype? Or is there maybe a prototype for DOM nodes in general?

Or do prototype objects only exist for built-in objects?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, but not in all browsers.  Internet Explorer 8 supports DOM prototypes (to a certain extent), as do Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.toggle = function () { 
    this.style.display = this.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

Many consider it bad practice to extend DOM objects via their prototype.  Kangax has a great article on the subject: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/.  However, DOM prototypes allow us to implement standards-based methods in environments that don't support them yet, much like shims for ECMAScript 5th Edition methods.

Comment: That indeed is a great article. I'll check it out and report back.

Comment: the example prototype doesn't hide the element. It's toggle

Comment: why just `HTMLDivElement` why not adding a prototype to all the HTML elements?

Comment: @vsync I... don't... know...! We're talking about an answer I wrote over 6 years ago so I have no idea why I chose HTMLDivElement for the example.  Of course, the whole example is pretty useless now as browsers later implemented the `hidden` attribute/property.  If anything you'd want to polyfill that.

Comment: would be nice then if you update your answer and make a new example

Answer (score 4):

In some browsers, DOM elements do expose a prototype object, which may also inherit from `Object.prototype`, but this is not universally true (for example, IE does not). In general, host objects such as DOM elements are not obliged to do this; in fact, host objects are not bound by many of the rules that apply to native JavaScript objects, so you should never rely on DOM elements to support this kind of thing.

I recommend [kangax's excellent article on this subject](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: @Tim I am asking this question because I would like to make your selection functions more convenient. For example, if I could add a `selec` object to HTML element nodes, then I could use your functions like so: `input.selec.get(); input.selec.set(5,8);`

Comment: @Šime: Ah, right. If you're using jQuery you can do something similar by augmenting `$.fn`, as plug-ins do. Otherwise, it's not possible in IE without some kind of element wrapper object (such as jQuery's).

Comment: Fortunately for us, IE is finally heading in the right direction - IE 9's DOM objects inherit from `Object.prototype`. @Šime wrapping is almost certainly the way to go, for the time being.

Comment: @Andy Wait a minute, in IE8- DOM objects don't inherit from Object.prototype?? What a bummer.

Comment: @Šime: yep.  IE 8 DOM prototypes were a half-assed effort.

Comment: @Tim Yea, I guess I'll use jQuery, after all. As for now, I wrapped your functions in an `selec` global object - http://vidasp.net/js/selection.js - so that I can use it like so: `selec.get(input); selec.set(input, 3, 4);`. I will expand this idea later.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what [prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) does, but is now considered extremely bad practise.
It's much better to use wrappers/handlers. Note, augmenting ANY native objects, especially the `Object` object, is bad practise.

read:

[Whats wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)
[Object.prototype is verboten](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/)

Addendum:

Whilst extending native objects in small projects it can be considered **safe** it will actually become an extremely bad habbit. It's only marginally less worse then littering the global scope with functions and variables. Not only do name collisions occur, but also implementation collisions. This will become more apearant the more libraries you mash up.

Keeping your implementation on your own objects is the only way to avoid ANY collisions, name, implementation or otherwise.

All that said, it's your perogative to do as you please, I however will not recommend anything thats widely accepted as sheer bad practise. I stick to my recommendation.

Comment: @BGerrissen Could you explain what exactly prototype.js does? I am unfamiliar with that library. Also, could you elaborate on using wrappers/handlers - what do you mean by that? Also, you say "augmenting ANY nativ objects, especially the Object object" - but I am not augmenting it, but its prototype object.

Comment: Recommending against augmenting any native object is fear mongering, IMO.  *String.prototype* extensions are very useful, for example, with the only potential downside being naming collisions in the future.

Comment: a) This is an essence of OOP, b) JS is throughly object oriented. Since when "now"?

Comment: @Sime Vidas & AndyE, extending native objects is perfectly legal and chances are you will get away with it just fine. PrototypeJS afterall has been a rather successful js toolkit. It's just not recommended for numerous reasons voiced by many people. /shrug it's just as easy to avoid it.

Comment: @Andy Yea, I wanted to say that, too, but was to lazy :). If you know what you're doing, and if you do it moderately, then it is OK.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, PrototypeJS is a JS toolkit very much like jQuery except jQuery uses a wrapper $() whereas prototype extends DOM elements directly. Check out the link.

Comment: @BGerrissen Yea, but using jQuery's wrapper is slower (as in performance) than using native APIs or the prototype chain. For example `this.parentNode.id` is several dozens of times faster than `$(this).parent().attr("id")`. That's why I would like to avoid wrappers for simple tasks.

Comment: @BGerrissen But what about the `String.prototype.trim` method (for example)? It is implemented in modern browsers, but not IE8 or below. It makes sense to detect if it's missing, and in that case manually implement it: `String.prototype.trim = function() { /* custom implementation */ };` Would you do that, or - if not - what would you do instead?

Comment: @BGerrissen - I don't believe you when you say "jQuery beats it in performance on every angle". Sure, on old IE the prototype way means extending every element which is slower than the wrapper way, but for the rest of browsers prototyping is actually faster.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, implementing .trim() the standard way in broken/old browsers is not augmentation imo. it's a hack to fix things. It becomes a problem when someone implements a new method that accepts different arguments cross libraries and eventually gets implemented as standard. Fact is, no one can predict it, so it's better to avoid it all together and only mess around with your own objects.

Comment: @BGerrissen Adding a `trim` property to the `String.prototype` object will augment the object, obviously. The term "augmenting" means "adding", "expanding", etc. You can say that in this particular case, augmentation is OK, but you cannot say that this is not augmentation.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, it's a bit tiring to argue about semantics, do you at least understand the jest of my awnser? No name/implementation collision is better than a chance of a name/implementation collision, even if the chance is minute, furthermore, it makes it easier to swap out implementations or even allow multiple implementations. I'm sure you can think of a few examples. It might not matter to you or even me when writing applications, but the recommendation should always be against, for the larger public.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, oh and do checkout PrototypeJS, it's actually quite shameful you haven't heard of it!!! :oP

Comment: @BGerrissen You haven't answered my question. Would you define the `trim` method on the `String.prototype` object for older browsers? If not, how else would you tackle this issue? (Let's assume that you need  the trim method for your project and you need it to be cross-browser.)

Comment: @BGerrissen I have heard of prototype.js, of course. :) What I meant is that I'm unfamiliar with how it works internally.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, no, used $.trim or simply my own implementation (it's a simple regexp afterall) for the last 3 years, before that, I extended js/dom natives to hell and back as well. It's not painful to type trim("string") instead of "string".trim(). For me it's also a code style thing.

Comment: @BGerrissen Yea, $.trim is probably the best choice here. However, consider using a milder language. Terms like "extremely" and even "much better" might be registered as exaggeration to some, which may lead to your answer loosing credibility.