# Javascript: add items to the Style Object

Tags: javascript, object, styles

On this page (not that W3Schools is always the best authority) it states that there is an HTML DOM Style Object which is something I have used many times:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Is this anything to do with JavaScript objects - as in, could I add to this object with the use of style.prototype? If not is there a way to add information to the style object that I can reference later?

Also, if I add to the style object, I presume that this information will ALWAYS be alive (as in will not die when the function that sets it finishes or until the browser or page is closed) and that any other Function or Object (Function ultimately inheriting from Object) will also always be able to access the added information - is this true?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well though it gives you some direction but `w3schools` is not an authority.

Answer (score 0):

A DOM element is a object and style is one of its properties. Different browsers have sometimes different ways to acess these.

The style you set to it will be available in any function that can reach that element. ie changes by different function do produce changes on the same object and they are available to all others.

Changes will stay until you remove the object from the DOM or change it.

Comment: So the use of Style.prototype will not work, at least not in all browsers? I haven't tried it yet, just thought I would ask around for some opinions on it...

Comment: @user1360809, some browsers do not allow that. You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193769/augmenting-the-prototype-of-dom-element-nodes

Comment: @user1360809 You need CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype instead. [CSSStyleDeclaration MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) Look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/FcqS9/)