# How do I change myFunction(elem) to elem.myFunction()?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering about javascript functions today. I know jQuery is a javascript library and can call a function on an element with a dot. And that javascript does the same thing sometimes (like with: `.toFixed()`)

```
Example (in jQuery):
$("#elem").css("width", 100);
```

Would it be possible to do the same with a regular javascript function? So what I would normally do is:

```
Example regular way:
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
function doSomethingToElement(elem){
   ...do something to elem here...
}
doSomethingToElement(elem);
```

What if I wanted to call the function differently with an elem.function() notation? Like:

```
elem.doSomethingToElement();
```

- **Can someone show me an example on how to do this?**
- **Sidenote: Some considerations of the advantages and disadvantages of using this notation would be interesting to hear as well.**

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193769/augmenting-the-prototype-of-dom-element-nodes) is what you need. Modifying the prototype of Dom Node Elements allows you to add functions onto them.

Comment: jQuery wraps HTML elements (and other things) in its own object. Extending an `HTMLElement` like `elem` _directly_ is not recommended, since it’s not guaranteed to be forward compatible. To define a method on your own objects, just define an object with a method on it: `const myObj = { elem: document.getElementById("elem"), doSomethingToElement(){ this.elem.` … something … `; } }`.

Comment: For those interested in this question: I can recommend googling 'methods'. A method is an invocable object property that can be invoked like a function. The `this` keyword used in those methods will refer to the object the method is bound to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as @jonas-w correctly suggests. I might add:

The crux of the answer is that the `elem` you have here:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
```

is not the same beast as `$("#elem")`

The latter is a jQuery object, endowed with all those cool jQuery methods. The former is vanilla DOM element. If you want to create objects and define methods that you can invoke on your object with the dot notation, you should do some reading, e.g., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS, where they provide this example:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greeting = function() {
        alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
    };
}
```

and explain it far better than I can. Essentially, that Person function is the Javascript equivalent of a class. You create the class definition (so to speak), and then instantiate instances (or objects) of that class, and call your methods on them with the dot notation. Hence,

```
person = new Person("Bob");
person.greeting();
```

There is also a singleton approach, e.g.,

```
myObject = {
    foo : function() { /* do something */ }
}
```

whereby you can then say `myObject.foo()`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do it you need to encapsulate or as it is called in JavaScript - a scope.

You can create a proxy to hold the element and than create some functions on it:

```
function ElementHolder(elem){
   this.elem = elem;
}

ElementHolder.prototype.doSomethingToElement = function(){
    //your code on this.elem
}
```

And to use it:

```
var elemHolder = new ElementHodler(document.getElementById('elem'));
elemHolder.doSomethingToElement ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function myFunction() {
throw("syntaxError: myFunction is not a 
function")
 //give error when myFunction() is called.
 myFunction.something = 
  function(parameters) {
   //code is here
}
}
```

It works by defining `myFunction` but making it appear like that doesn't exist,
Then it adds *`.something`* in the function.
Then the code runs when you call `myFunction.something()`.

Hope this helps you (or someone else)!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply extends *Element.prototype* :

```
Element.prototype.log = function(){
  console.log(this);
};
```

You can use it like:

```
document.body.log();
```